# Stucked in Jupgrade extension while migrating to joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Since thursday nyt, I got stucked on upgrading my joomla website 1.5.26 to 2.5 in the very first step which is cleanining and caching. I already disabled rest of the plugins except mootools plugins. I also reinstalled the latest mootools plugin for joomla and ; is also removed from the php_curl in my php.ini file. Any ideas about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Extensions > jUpgrade.
- Click Parameters.
- Select Yes for the Skip Download option.
- Select Yes for the Skip Decompress option.
- Select No for the Delete previous migrationoption

[image]
 - Click Save.

- Create a folder in your Joomla root called jupgrade.
- Download Joomla 2.5.4 and extract it in the jupgrade folder.

  http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16914/73508/Joomla_2.5.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip
- If you have already run jUpgrade and it failed, clear your browser
  cache now. Click Start Upgrade.
- If you still have problems with jUpgrade, see the following forum
  post on jUpgrade; it addresses this issue.
- Once you have successfully upgraded Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.4, you can
  upgrade Joomla 2.5.4 to 2.5.6, but I would wait until Joomla comes
  out with another release. Joomla 2.5.6 is still full of bugs and
  inconsistencies.

Comment: Did that but still having the same issue :(((